# Java reflection - get getter method with different name

Tags: java, reflection

Is there any way I can get the `getter` method of a field, which is having different name from the usual standards?

```
class Employee {

        private String name;
        private String dept;

        public String getTheName() {
            return name;
        }

        public void setName(String name) {
            this.name = name;
        }

        public String getTheDept() {
            return dept;
        }

        public void setDept(String dept) {
            this.dept = dept;
        }
    }
```

I know using reflection we can get the `getter` method of a field if the `getter` method is following the usual standard.
Example:

1. name ==> getName
2. dept ==> getDept

But in our project, we are having a different convention than usual.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: As long as there *is* a consistent pattern that you can follow, you can get the method. Reflection actually doesn't care about those naming conventions, that's purely on higher levels. Reflection simply deals in methods and fields and doesn't care or know that a given method is a getter.

Comment: And kind of unrelated, and purely due to my curiosity: Why did you chose to follow **a** convention, but not the single most widely used convention in the Java space? IMO the primary reason to not follow the bean properties naming convention is if you don't need a convention at all.

Comment: You would have to know the name of the method or something about it that distinguishes it from the others since the signatures of differently named methods could all be the same.  Thus you wouldn't know which to choose.

Comment: @JoachimSauer I was wondering who wrote that code, it is an existing project where changes are very difficult

Comment: @user16320675 well, when you follow Java Beans conventions, the classes in the `java.beans` package do offer such functionality, i.e. `Introspector.getBeanInfo(Employee.class).getPropertyDescriptors()[0] .getReadMethod()`. But it’s the getter for a property, not a field. Whether a property is backed by a field, is an irrelevant implementation detail of the class.

Comment: @SuganthanMadhavanPillai I think, you have to explain your actual use case. Why is it relevant to get “the getter method of a field”? For the caller of a method, it doesn’t matter whether the private field has the same name, or whether there is a corresponding field at all.